# Rdkit.Chem.Draw.savefig() creates empty figures

Tags: python

I can draw a molecule in a jupyter notebook with RDKit. Though, when I use the savefig() method only a white canvas is saved. No molecule is saved.

```
%pylab inline
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

smiles = 'CCC'
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
fig = Draw.MolToMPL(m)
title('Test')
fig.savefig('mol.jpeg')
```

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have to set `bbox_inches` to tight. Without that rdkit does not fit the molecule into the canvas and might plot an empty figure.

```
fig.savefig('mol.jpeg', bbox_inches='tight')
```